# Multiple -and -or in PowerShell Where-Object statement

Tags: powershell, windows-7, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

```
PS H:\> Invoke-Command -computername SERVERNAME { Get-ChildItem -path E:\dfsroots\datastore2\public} | Where-Object {{ $_.e
xtension-match "xls" -or $_.extension-match "xlk" } -and  { $_.creationtime -ge "06/01/2014"}}
```

Above is my code example. I'm trying to remotely run this PowerShell code on my file server and have it return all .xls and .xlk files with a creation date on or later than 6/1/2014. When I run this code it starts spitting out all of the folders in that remote location. If I only compare two things like so:

```
PS H:\> Invoke-Command -computername SERVERNAME { Get-ChildItem -path E:\dfsroots\datastore2\public} | Where-Object { $_.extension-match "xls" -and  $_.creationtime -ge "06/01/2014"}
```

Only the xls files created on or after that date display. What's going on here? Do I need to use something other than nest `-and` and `-or` statements?

Comment: Note that breaking down the command into multiple "where" statements didn't work either. I'd enter a command like: PS H:\> Invoke-Command -computername SERVERNAME { Get-ChildItem -path E:\dfsroots\datastore2\public} | Where-Object { $_.ex
tension-match "xls" -or $_.extension-match "xlk" } | where-object { $_.creationtime -ge "06/01/2014"} 

And it starts spitting out xlsx files which is not what I want.

Comment: Use parenthesis not curly brackets to enclose options, so `Where{($_.Extension -Match "xls" -or $_.Extension -Match "xlk") -and $_.CreationTime -ge "06/01/2014"}`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Even using parenthesis the results still spit out xlsx files as well.

Comment: @WinskiTech re: Markdown. click the help link next to the comment box for formatting help. Surround code with backticks `\``.

Comment: Then don't use -Match, use -eq instead.

Answer (score 71):

By wrapping your comparisons in `{}` in your first example you are creating ScriptBlocks; so the PowerShell interpreter views it as `Where-Object { <ScriptBlock> -and <ScriptBlock> }`. Since the `-and` operator operates on boolean values, PowerShell casts the ScriptBlocks to boolean values. In PowerShell anything that is not empty, zero or null is true. The statement then looks like `Where-Object { $true -and $true }` which is always true.

Instead of using `{}`, use parentheses `()`.

Also you want to use `-eq` instead of `-match` since match uses regex and will be true if the pattern is found anywhere in the string (try: `'xlsx' -match 'xls'`).

```
Invoke-Command -computername SERVERNAME { 
    Get-ChildItem -path E:\dfsroots\datastore2\public | 
        Where-Object {($_.extension -eq ".xls" -or $_.extension -eq ".xlk") -and ($_.creationtime -ge "06/01/2014")}
}
```

A better option is to filter the extensions at the `Get-ChildItem` command.

```
Invoke-Command -computername SERVERNAME { 
    Get-ChildItem -path E:\dfsroots\datastore2\public\* -Include *.xls, *.xlk | 
        Where-Object {$_.creationtime -ge "06/01/2014"}
}
```

Comment: Parenthesis did not fix the issue, only changed what came out, I'm getting xlsx files when all I'm trying to search for is xls and xlk files.

Comment: See my edit. The `-match` operator will match anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 10):

You're using curvy-braces when you should be using parentheses.

A where statement is kept inside a scriptblock, which is defined using curvy baces `{ }`. To isolate/wrap you tests, you should use parentheses `()`.

I would also suggest trying to do the filtering on the remote computer. Try:

```
Invoke-Command -computername SERVERNAME {
    Get-ChildItem -path E:\dfsroots\datastore2\public |
    Where-Object { ($_.extension -eq "xls" -or $_.extension -eq "xlk") -and $_.creationtime -ge "06/01/2014" }
}
```

Comment: Parenthesis did not fix the issue, only changed what came out, I'm getting xlsx files when all I'm trying to search for is xls and xlk files.

Comment: You had also used the wrong operator. Sorry for not catching that. You need to use `-eq` to get exact matches. `-match` would include all results with extentions that contain the phrase "xls". :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here:

[How to properly -filter multiple strings in a PowerShell copy script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616581/how-to-properly-filter-multiple-strings-in-a-powershell-copy-script)

You have to use `-Include`  flag for `Get-ChildItem`

My Example:

```
$Location = "C:\user\files" 
$result = (Get-ChildItem $Location\* -Include *.png, *.gif, *.jpg)
```

**Dont forget put "*" after path location.**