# How to, using CMD/Powershell, find all files in a directory (including subdirectories), and then display files that have certain extensions

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I need to make a script using CMD/Powershell that can find all files in a directory (and subdirectories) that end in extensions associated with media 
files. I have a Unix script that can do this:

```
 find /directory/ | egrep -e ".*.(jpg|tif|png|gif|wav|mp3|ogg|flac|wma|aac|m4a|flv|webm|ogv|gif|gifv|avi|wmv|mp4|mpg|3gp)"
```

(I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but it works, and has no problems for me.)

However, I need to do this for Windows. The file types are as follows:

- jpg
- tif
- png
- gif
- wav
- mp3
- ogg
- flac
- wma
- aac
- m4a
- flv
- webm
- ogv
- gif
- gifv
- avi
- wmv
- mp4
- mpg
- 3gp

Edit: Even though I got the right answer, the possible duplicate is not correct. This is because I needed it to be outputted to a file. My script that I wrote using bgalea's answer is as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
set $ext=*.jpg *.tif *.png *.gif *.wav *.mp3 *.ogg *.flac *.wma *.aac *.m4a *.flv *.webm *.ogv *.gif *.gifv *.avi *.wmv *.mp4 *.mpg *.3gp
dir /s/b c:\Users%$ext% > mediafiles.txt
echo The locations of the media files were copied to mediafiles.txt 
pause
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly -filter multiple strings in a PowerShell copy script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616581/how-to-properly-filter-multiple-strings-in-a-powershell-copy-script)

Comment: @user4317867 Edited in why that's not correct.

Comment: Then we'd use `Get-ChildItem $originalPath\* -Include *.gif, *.jpg, *.xls*, *.doc*, *.pdf*, *.wav*, .ppt*` to list the items, look up the `FullName` property and finally output that to a text file.   `(gci -Path C:\Scripts\* -Include *.csv, *.txt).fullname | out-file -FilePath c:\temp\test.txt;ii c:\temp\test.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 dir /s /b c:\*.3gp c:\*.mpg* c:\*.mp4
```

Etc

`C:\` says to start at c:. `/s` does sub folders, `/b` gives only names.

Comment: You'll better make a list : `set $ext=*.jpg *.tif *.png` and then `dir /s/b c:\%$List%` +1

Comment: +1, But you have an unwanted `*` after `c:\*.mpg`. Also, you can save some typing by PUSHD C:\ before running the command, so that you don't need to include the path with every extension.

Comment: See `pushd /?` - also see Setting a UNC working directory from a shortcut at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file#Setting_a_UNC_working_directory_from_a_shortcut - the last two paragraphs (written by me)

Answer (score 3):

Powershell FTW!

```
$extensions = @("*.jpg", "*.tif"...ect ect)

Get-ChildItem C:\temp -Include $extensions -Recurse
```