# How to -Include using a variable with multiple criteria

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy files with names that fulfills a given set of criteria from one folder to another. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18626464/1461602), I found that the `-Include` statement could be used for this.

My issue is that I need the criteria to be user-specified (through a variable), with the possibility of containing multiple criteria. That is, I try to do the following:

```
# THIS WORKS FINE
$includeFiles = "*tests.jar"
Copy-Item "from/path" "to/path" -Include $includeFiles 

# THIS RETURNS NOTHING
$includeFiles = "*tests.jar, other.jar"
Copy-Item "from/path" "to/path" -Include $includeFiles
```

How do I work around this issue? Is it somehow possible to "destring" the variable, use another syntax or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# THIS WORKS FINE
$copyPattern = "*tests.jar", "other.jar"
Copy-Item "from/path" "to/path" -Include $copyPattern
```

The point is that the argument to `-Include` is an array of strings, each string is a pattern to include. The way you wrote it would require a comma and space in the file name. So, unless you have such files, nothing would be included.

If you are positive that the pattern will never include commas and you'd rather just have a single string, you can of course convert it to an array:

```
$copyPatterns = "*tests.jar, other.jar" -split ', '
```

Note that parsing works differently in arguments to commands, which is why the following does work as well:

```
Copy-Item from/path to/path -Include *tests.jar,other.jar
```

Comment: Great answer! In my scenario, the input variable has to be a single string, but splitting that string before using it to Include works great. Thanks!