# powershell word to pdf

Tags: powershell, pdf, ms-word

I modified what someone else had on this forum, based on a successful use of powershell Excel to pdf with no success.  Any ideas on my failing in the following code?  My goal is to be able to convert an entire folder of doc and docx documents to pdf without opening the native applications.  Thanks in advance:

```
# Acquire a list of DOC files in a folder
$Word = New-Object -ComObject word.application 
$path = "c:\Users\Desktop\Test" 
$formats = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFixedFormatType" -as [type]
$Word.visible = $false
$fileTypes = "*.docx","*doc"
$Files = GET-CHILDITEM $path -include $fileTypes

Foreach ($File in $Files) {
    $filepath = Join-Path -path $path -childpath ($File.basename +".pdf")
    $Doc = $Word.open($File.fullname, 3)
    $Doc.Saved= $true
    "Converting $File to pdf ... $destPath"
    # Save this File as a PDF in Word 2010/2013
    $Doc.ExportAsFixedFormat($formats::wdTypePDF, $path)
    $Doc.FullName -replace '\.doc?$', '.pdf'
    $Doc.Close()
}
$Word.Quit()
```

Comment: Just an FYI, when you use the `Word.Application` comobject, you *are* opening the native application.

Comment: True, but the $Word.visible=$false means the application only runs in the background, I believe...

Comment: are you getting a error?

Comment: `$Word.open` > `$Word.Documents.Open`, for a start. And your `Get-ChildItem` does not return anything, so you never enter the `foreach` loop.

Comment: @sodawillow thats becuase its getting the files from a folder with a given type...I would assume its not empty on the users end.

Comment: @sodawillow what if I removed line 5 and changed line 6-9 to read as follows:  $Files = GET-CHILDITEM -Path $path -include *.doc, *.docx -recurse

Foreach ($File in $Files) {
    $filepath = Join-Path -path $path -childpath ($File.basename +".pdf")
    $Doc = $Word.Documents.Open($File.fullname, 3)

Comment: @ArcSet - no error, just nothing happening...

Comment: @ArcSet & OP: [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616581/how-to-properly-filter-multiple-strings-in-a-powershell-copy-script). OP: please test the code yourself, and check the errors you get, to correct your mistakes. Also, [here is a useful tutorial for you](https://learn-powershell.net/2014/12/31/beginning-with-powershell-and-word/).

Comment: Also....your $Formats is equal to nothing

Comment: @sodawillow okey dokey  good point.  Still no dice... no errors generated and also no pdfs generated!  I'll figure it out eventually...  I'm pretty new to powershell and thought you might see something obvious other than what was discussed.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ArcSet ouch!  That's a Monday for ya.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$path = 'C:\tests'

$wd = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include *.doc, *.docx -Recurse |
    ForEach-Object {
        $doc = $wd.Documents.Open($_.Fullname)
        $pdf = $_.FullName -replace $_.Extension, '.pdf'
        $doc.ExportAsFixedFormat($pdf,17,$false,0,3,1,1,0,$false, $false,0,$false, $true)
        $doc.Close()
    }
$wd.Quit()
```

This will Go trough the folder and then look for .doc and .docx files

It then opens each file creates a new save name and exports to PDF

You can learn more about the ExportAsFixedFormat from
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb256835(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: `ExportAsFixedFormat`: 13 parameters. Not less. Now I understand why my ISE was going crazy over this specific line... **Always** read the docs! %)

Comment: Parameter number 5 is the `WdExportRange`, which determines how many pages are exported; I found with it set to `3` as in the answer I only got the first page out, setting to `0` exports the entire document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdexportrange