# Word ExportAsFixedFormat

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I'm trying to do a tricky script to export to pdf, some Word files that are corrected, but with "SIMPLE revision marks".
So for now I use ExportAsFixedFormat() from Microsoft but the WdExportItem option is binary (0 or 7) : ALL revision marks or none.
Does someone as an idea of an api that would help me in this goal ?

Below, my powershell script :

```
$path = 'C:\path'

$wd = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include *.doc, *.docx -Recurse |
    ForEach-Object {
        $doc = $wd.Documents.Open($_.Fullname)
        $pdf = $_.FullName -replace $_.Extension, '.pdf'
        $doc.ExportAsFixedFormat($pdf,17,$false,0,0,0,0,7,$false, $false,0,$false, $true)
        $doc.Close()
    }
$wd.Quit()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [powershell word to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46286292/powershell-word-to-pdf)

Comment: See my answer for complete working and tested program. The trick here is to programmatticaly set `Markup Insertions` to `None` and `Markup Deletions` to `Hidden`

Comment: ArcSet, no it doesn't, because my issue isn't about exporting to pdf but concerns the specification of revision marks. William answered my question.

Comment: @BelowSea: If I answered your question, please accept the answer: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Word 2019

> Disclaimer: The settings that my program changes to meet the
> requirements seem to be sticky, i.e., although I don't save the doc
> after changing the markup settings, they persist across closing and
> re-opening the document. My program does not attempt to put the markup
> settings back to their original settings

The trick here is to programmatically set `Markup Insertions` to `None` and `Markup Deletions` to `Hidden`

These two lines of code accomplish this. See **Code** below for complete working and tested program

```
$wordApp.Options.InsertedTextMark = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdInsertedTextMark]::wdInsertedTextMarkNone
$wordApp.Options.DeletedTextMark = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdDeletedTextMark]::wdDeletedTextMarkHidden
```

Here are the corresponding settings in Word

[image]

**Sample docx input**

[image]

**Sample pdf output**

[image]

**Code**

```
cls

try
{
    $path = 'C:\temp\'
    $Error.Clear()

    $wordApp = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
    $wordApp.Visible = $false
    $docOpen = $false

    $wordDocFqPathList = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include *.doc, *.docx -Recurse)

    foreach ($wordDocFqPath in $wordDocFqPathList)
    {
        $doc = $wordApp.Documents.Open($wordDocFqPath.FullName, $false, $true)
        $docOpen = $true

        $doc.Activate()

        $doc.ActiveWindow.View.Type = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdViewType]::wdPrintView
        $doc.ShowRevisions = $true

        #set tracked changes to show change bars only
        $doc.ActiveWindow.View.RevisionsFilter.View = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRevisionsView]::wdRevisionsViewFinal
        $doc.ActiveWindow.View.RevisionsFilter.Markup = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRevisionsMarkup]::wdRevisionsMarkupSimple
        $wordApp.Options.InsertedTextMark = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdInsertedTextMark]::wdInsertedTextMarkNone
        $wordApp.Options.DeletedTextMark = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdDeletedTextMark]::wdDeletedTextMarkHidden

        $pdfDocFqPath = $wordDocFqPath.FullName.Replace(".docx", ".pdf").Replace(".doc", ".pdf")

        #https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat
        $doc.ExportAsFixedFormat($pdfDocFqPath,`
                                    [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat]::wdExportFormatPDF,`
                                    $false,`
                                    [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportOptimizeFor]::wdExportOptimizeForPrint,`
                                    [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportRange]::wdExportAllDocument,`
                                    0, 0,`
                                    [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportItem]::wdExportDocumentWithMarkup,`
                                    $true, $false)

        $doc.Close([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions]::wdDoNotSaveChanges)
        $docOpen = $false
    }
}
finally
{
    if ($docOpen -eq $true)
    {
        $doc.Close([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions]::wdDoNotSaveChanges)
    }

    $wordApp.Quit()
}
```

Comment: I didn't see it this way, but, yes, these lines of code, was what was missing to my script. Thank you William Charlton for sharing this trick !

Comment: @BelowSea If I answered your question, please accept my answer