# powershell performance: Get-ChildItem -Include vs. Get-ChildItem | Where-Object

Tags: powershell

I tried a few options to iterate my directories and get a huge performance difference between the following commands:

Slow:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Force -Recurse -Depth 3 -Include '$tf'
```

Fast:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Force -Recurse -Depth 3 | Where-Object Name -eq '$tf'
```

Could someone explain me why the first statement is much slower than the second?

Comment: Do you remember if you could've used the `-Filter` switch to achieve your goal? According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.3#-filter) "Filters are **more efficient** than other parameters. The provider applies filter when the cmdlet gets the objects rather than having PowerShell filter the objects after they're retrieved."

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It is working even better than the Where-Object (in my case).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Get-ChildItem` is a provider cmdlet - that means that a bulk of its actual work is offloaded to an underlying provider, likely the `FileSystem` provider in your case.

The provider itself doesn't actually support the `-Include`/`-Exclude` parameters, that's one of the few things that the cmdlet takes care off - and for the file system provider this is ultra heavy double-work, because the cmdlet needs to recurse down through the file system hierarchy to figure out whether it needs to apply an exclusion or an inclusion based on a parent directory name, you can [see how this is implemented here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/SessionStateContainer.cs#L1734).

So by using `-Include` against the file system provider, you're asking PowerShell to do an immense amount of double work.