# PowerShell - How to use multiple filter's with -not? (See example.)

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to move .pdf's based on text that could be present anywhere in the file name and it's not working.  It executes without error, but it doesn't move the files.

All the .pdf's with 'Sold' in the filename go to one place and all the ones without 'sold' in the file name go to a different place.

```
get-childitem -Recurse -path $sourcePathPDF  {-filter '*.pdf' -and '*Sold*'} | move-item -Destination $destinationPathSoldPDF 
get-childitem -Recurse -path $sourcePathPDF  {-filter '*.pdf' -not '*Sold*'} | move-item -Destination $destinationPathPDF
```

Am I filtering/using the -not incorrectly?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You don't need `-not`, you need `-notlike`: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse |Where-Object { $_.Name -like '*.pdf' -and $_.Name -notlike '*Sold*'}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `-Filter` only accepts a *single* pattern.
- **Use `-Include` and `-Exclude`** instead<sup>[1]</sup>, both of which **accept *multiple* patterns**.

```
# Two inclusion patterns
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $sourcePathPDF -Include *.pdf, *sold*

# One inclusion, one exclusion pattern.
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $sourcePathPDF -Include *.pdf -Exclude *Sold*
```

**Note**:

- As of PowerShell 7.2, **`-Include` and `-Exclude` are hampered by performance problems**, as [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) notes, **due to their *inefficient implementation*** (see [GitHub issue #8662](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8662)), so the `Where-Object`-based solution discussed below may be called for not just for more complex matching logic, but for performance alone.
- `-Include` and `-Exclude` use PowerShell's [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards), which have more features and lack the legacy quirks of the platform-native patterns that `-Filter` supports - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60171419/45375) for more information.

  - The **upside of using `-Filter` is that its *much faster*** than `-Include` / `-Exclude`, because `-Filter` filters _at the source, whereas `-Include` / `-Exclude` filters are applied *after* the fact, by PowerShell, after *all* items have been retrieved first.
- ***Without `-Recurse`*, `-Include` and `-Exclude` do not work as expected** - use `Get-Item * -Include/-Exclude ...` instead  - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/45375).

---

**For more sophisticated pattern matching and/or better performance**, **pipe to a [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) call** in whose script block you can use the wildcard-based [`-like` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-like), as Mathias recommends; alternatively, for even more flexible matching, you can use the regex-based [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch). To adapt Mathias' `-like`-based `Where-Object` solution from the comment:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse  -Path $sourcePathPDF |
  Where-Object { $_.Name -like '*.pdf' -and $_.Name -notlike '*Sold*' }
```

For (currently) **best performance** you can ***pre-filter* with `-Filter`**:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $sourcePathPDF -Filter *.pdf |
  Where-Object { $_.Name -notlike '*Sold*' }
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

- `-Filter`, `-Include`, and `-Exclude` are *string*-typed - there is no support for passing [script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }` with arbitrary expression to them.

  - While *pipeline-binding* parameters may accept script blocks, in order to supply parameter values *dynamically*, based on the input object at hand (a feature known as [delay-bind script blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375)), neither of these parameters support such binding, so passing script blocks doesn't apply.
- What actually happened in your attempt is that the *stringified* version of script block `{-filter '*.pdf' -and '*Sold*'}` - which is its *verbatim content* (excluding `{` and `}`) - was *positionally* bound to the `-Filter` parameter.

  - That is, you effectively passed `-Filter "-filter '*.pdf' -and '*Sold*'"`, which predictably didn't match any files, because *verbatim* `-filter '*.pdf' -and '*Sold*'` was used as the pattern.

---

<sup>[1] Note that you may even *combine* `-Filter` with `-Include` / `-Exclude`, in which case the `-Filter` argument is applied *first*, at the source. Because of how `-Include` and `-Exclude` currently work, this is only works meaningfully if the input path ends in `\*` or `-Recurse` is used - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/45375).</sup>

Comment: It's probably worth noting that combining `-Recurse` and `-Include`/`-Exclude` will incur [a serious performance penalty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52293871/powershell-performance-get-childitem-include-vs-get-childitem-where-object/52294304#52294304) to the point where it's worse than just piping all file system items to `Where-Object` :)

Comment: Thanks, @MathiasR.Jessen - please see my update. I had no idea how slow `-Include` and `-Exclude` actually are. While they are _inherently, of necessity_ slower than `-Filter`, there is _no_ justification for performing worse than an equivalent command that involves an additional `Where-Object` call for post-filtering. There are several issues in the repo re `-Include` and `-Exclude` already, but I'll see if I can find one that calls out this specific problem - if you happen to know of one, do let me know.

Comment: Wow, thank you both.  I'm not sure if I've ever seen such a good answer template @mklemento.  The 'What you tried' section should be included much more often in answers as it helps specifically fill in the knowledge gap the questioner has so well.  Great job and thank you for the help!

Comment: @Mathias. I've found the relevant issue (also added to the answer): https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8662. Turns out that I created it myself, in 2019 - and you commented :)

Comment: @mklement0 LGTM! I'm afraid I haven't kept on top related issues. I tend to favor `-Filter` + `... |Where-Object` for exclusions whenever possible, (instead of moving both include and exclude logic to `Where-Object`)

Comment: @Mathias :) Re combining `-Filter` with `Where-Object`: Makes perfect sense (the answer already shows an example).

Answer (score 0):

With -not, you would need parentheses because of operator precedence (without parentheses "-not $_.name" becomes "False"):

```
get-childitem | where {$_.name -like '*.pdf' -and -not ($_.name -like '*Sold*')}
```

You could also get into wmi for some speed (doesn't cover c:\users?):

```
Get-WmiObject CIM_DataFile -filter 'Drive="C:" and Extension="pdf" and 
  not name like "%Sold%" and path like "\\%"'
```