# Bulk rename file(s) using Powershell from csv\txt file

Tags: powershell, file-rename

As the title suggests I am trying to create a Powershell script to rename multiple files. The script refers to a csv file which contains a string in a csv file "column A". If the result is true then I would like to rename the file from "Column B".

Ive managed to get my code to work based on a string but this is the next stage - can anyone help me please?

Current Code:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
  Where {($_.Name -like "*blah*")} |
  Rename-Item -NewName {[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.fullname) + ".BackupFile"}
```

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes that your CSV file contains the file names *with* extension - adjust as needed.

- Build a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) from the CSV whose entries are keyed by `Column A` values and each contain the corresponding `Column B` value.
- Filter the `Get-ChildItem` output with `Where-Object` to only process files whose name is present as a key in the hashtable.

  - Note that switch `-File` is added to the `Get-ChildItem` call below, so as to process files only (not also directory objects).
- Rename each matching file to the value of the relevant hashtable entry.

```bash
# Build a hashtable from the CSV that with old-name-new-name pairs.
$ht = [ordered] @{} # Note: you can omit [ordered] in this case.
Import-Csv file.csv |
  ForEach-Object { $ht[$_.'Column A'] = $_.'Column B' }

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
  Where-Object { $ht.Contains($_.Name) } |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $ht[$_.Name] } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note: As an alternative to filtering `Get-ChildItem` output with `Where-Object` after the fact, you could use the former's `-Include` parameter as follows:

- `-Include $ht.Keys`
- However, up to at least PowerShell 7.2.x, `-Include` is actually *slower* than a post-filtering solution - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70068976/45375).