# Save Path of File only if match found

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script which searches through folders recursively to look for a user supplied string to search for and replace. In addition, I want to be able to save the file path of only the files that had the match.  Currently my script is saving all the files it looks through (all the .config), not just the matches.  Here is my code that works for saving all. How do I only write the file paths that had a match to my output file?

```
$rootDir = GCI $dirPath -recurse -include *.config
    ForEach($dir in $rootDir)
    {
        (Get-Content $dir).replace($oldString,$newString) | Set-Content $dir
      
        $dir.FullName >> $filePathName
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're missing a check before the replacement: only output the file's absolute path if the content matches `$oldString`.

Also your code could benefit from pipeline processing and the use of `-Raw` for efficiency:

```
Get-ChildItem $dirPath -Recurse -Include *.config | ForEach-Object {
    # `-Raw` reads the content as a single multi-line string
    $content = $_ | Get-Content -Raw
    # if there is a match
    if ($content -like "*$oldString*") {
        # replace and store the updated version of the file
        $content.Replace($oldString, $newString) | Set-Content $_.FullName -NoNewLine
        # and output the fullpath
        $_.FullName
    }
} | Set-Content $filePathName
```

Comment: good call, thanks @mklement0

Comment: Thank you both!  With or without the -NoNewLine I still get each path on a separate line, which is what I want!  So are you saying that more lines could be added without this?  I am fairly new to PowerShell and appreciate you knowledge for efficiency.

Comment: @taraloca glad to help. he mentioned `-NoNewLine` mainly because otherwise those files we're replacing will end up with 2 empty lines at the end instead of only 1

Answer (score 0):

To **complement [Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76852854/45375)**, which offers an effective solution that additionally speeds up the operation with the use of [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)'s `-Raw` switch, which reads a given text file *in full*, as a *single, (typically) multiline* string.

An **additional optimization** is possible:

- .NET's [`.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Replace) string-replacement method returns the input instance as-is if no actual replacement was performed (the same applies analogously to PowerShell's regex-based [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator)).
- Thus, if the input string and the result string are the exact same [`[string]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String) instance, the implication is that NO substitutions were performed, from which you can infer that the search string wasn't present.

  - The .NET [`[object]::.ReferenceEquals()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Object.ReferenceEquals) tests two references (variables) for whether they refer to the exact same object.

Therefore, using this technique saves you from having to search the file contents *twice* (once to *look* for the string, and again during replacement), because you can infer from the result of the `.Replace()` call whether the search string was present in the file at hand:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dirPath -Recurse -Filter *.config | ForEach-Object {
    $content = $_ | Get-Content -Raw
    # Perform the desired replacement.
    $modifiedContent = $content.Replace($oldString, $newString)
    # Were actual replacements made? If not, the implication is that
    # $oldString wasn't present in the file at hand.
    $actuallyModified = -not [object]::ReferenceEquals($content, $modifiedContent)
    if ($actuallyModified) {         
      $modifiedContent | Set-Content -NoNewLine -LiteralPath $_.FullName # Save modified content.
      $_.FullName # Output the path of the modified file to the pipeline.
    }
} | Set-Content -LiteralPath $filePathName
```

<sup>Note the use of `-LiteralPath` to ensure that all paths are treated literally (verbatim); by default, with the (positionally impied) `-Path` parameter, paths are interpreted as [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) expressions, which notably causes problems with literal paths that contain `[` and `]`. Due to a *bug* in Windows PowerShell (since fixed in PowerShell (Core) 7+), `-LiteralPath` cannot be combined with `-Include` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70068976/45375) - which is why `-Filter` is used instead (which is actually a blessing, because it is much faster than `-Include`).</sup>

**Character-encoding caveat:**

- `Get-Content` reads text files into .NET strings, without storing information about the file's original character encoding.
- PowerShell's file-writing cmdlets such as `Set-Content` and `Out-File` / `>` operate on .NET strings and by default use *their* default character encoding (which is fixed an unrelated to any input):

  - In *Windows PowerShell*, it is ANSI for `Set-Content` and "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) for `Out-File` / `>` (other cmdlets may have different defaults - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76853154/45375)).
  - More sensibly, *PowerShell (Core) 7+* now uses the same default character encoding for *all* cmdlets, which is BOM-less UTF-8 (in Windows PowerShell you can use `-Encoding utf8`, but you *always get a BOM* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66553739/45375) for a workaround).
- **Upshot**:

  - You **may have to use the `-Encoding` parameter** to get the desired output character encoding.
  - If you need **to match an input file's encoding, you must *know what it is*** (so you can pass its name to `-Encoding`).