# Powershell IO.FileSystemWatcher filters

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

I have created a `IO.filesystemwatcher` to monitor a folder and take an action when certain file types are written to the location. I am looking for file types `.jpg` and `.tmp`. I have named the filter as a variable, and the filter works when including one file type, but not two types.

Code below functions correctly:

```
$filter = '*.jpg'
New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $Folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $true;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}
```

Code below functions correctly:

```
$filter = '*.tmp'
New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $Folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $true;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}
```

Code below DOES NOT function:

```
$filter = '*.tmp','*jpg'
New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $Folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $true;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}
```

I have also tried `$filter = '*.tmp' -or '*jpg'`

I am sure there's a different way to do this to make it work, but I am not very good at working with `IO.filesystemwatcher`. Any recommendations are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`.Filter` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.filter?view=netframework-4.7.2) is `[string]`-typed and supports only a *single* wildcard expressions; from the docs:

> Use of multiple filters such as `"*.txt|*.doc"` is not supported.

It sounds like you'll have to:

- either: watch for changes to *all* files, by setting `.Filter` to `''` (the empty string), and then perform your own filtering inside your event handler.
- or: set up a separate watcher instance for each filter (wildcard pattern). <sup>Thanks, [mhhollomon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10741691/mhhollomon).</sup>

Comment: @mhhollomon: Good idea, thanks - I've added your suggestion to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Filter is a single string.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616581/how-to-properly-filter-multiple-strings-in-a-powershell-copy-script) 
You can inspect the raised event to find the full path and compare it to your filters:

```
$Script:filter = @('*.txt','*jpg','*.csv')
If($FileWatcher){$FileWatcher.Dispose();$FileWatcher = $null}
$FileWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $true;
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
    Path =  'C:\Users\proxb\Desktop\DropBox\'
}
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileWatcher  -EventName Created -Action {
    Write-Host "File: $($event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath) was $($event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType) at $($event.TimeGenerated) "
    $Script:filter | ForEach{
        If($event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath -like $_){
            Write-Host "$($event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath) matched $_" 
            #Do something here
        }
    }
}
```