# Multiple filter in Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, copy-paste

I want to apply multiple `filter` in *PowerShell* script as of now I am able to add only single `filter` like below

```
Get-Childitem "D:\SourceFolder" -recurse -filter "*kps.jpg" 
    | Copy-Item -Destination "D:\DestFolder"
```

From the above query I able to to copy only one file **`kps.jpg`**  from `SourceFolder` to `DestFolder`, how can I pass multiple names to copy more than one file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly -filter multiple strings in a PowerShell copy script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616581/how-to-properly-filter-multiple-strings-in-a-powershell-copy-script)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To filter on more than one condition, use the `Include` parameter instead of the `-Filter`.

```
Get-Childitem "D:\SourceFolder" -Recurse -Include "*kps.jpg", "*kps.png", "*kps.bmp" | 
Copy-Item -Destination "D:\DestFolder"
```

---

<sup>Note: The `Include` only works if you also specify `-Recurse` or have the path end in `\*` like in `Get-Childitem "D:\SourceFolder\*"`</sup>

---

Note2: As [Lee_Daily](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) commented, `-Filter` would work faster that `-Include` (or `-Exclude`) parameters. Filters are more efficient than other parameters, because the provider applies them when the cmdlet gets the objects. Otherwise, PowerShell filters the objects after they are retrieved. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1#parameters)

The downside of `-Filter` is that you can only supply one single filename filter whereas `-Include` allows for an array of wildcard filters.

Comment: i vaguely recall reading that the `-Include` & `-Exclude` parameters do their filtering in the cmdlet while the `-Filter` parameter has the provider do the filtering. is that correct - and if so, is it worth mentioning in your notes that it will be slower because of that?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I have added this info as a second note. Thanks for your input.

Comment: kool! you are most welcome ... and thanks for the link! [*grin*]