# How to copy specific files and paste to another location keeping structure?

Tags: powershell, copy

My file structure is like this:

> - ParentFolder
>
>   - ChildFolder_1
>
>     - xyz.mat
>     - abc.mat
>     - image_xy.mat
>   - ChildFolder_2
>
>     - xyz.mat
>     - abc.mat
>     - image_xy.mat
>   - ChildFolder_N
>
>     - xyz.mat
>     - abc.mat
>     - image_xy.mat

I want to copy only `image_xy.mat` from each folder and paste it to another location in same hierarchy.

So far with the following reference:
[How to use powershell copy-item and keep structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432290/how-to-use-powershell-copy-item-and-keep-structure)

I tried doing this:

```
$source = "H:\data"
$dest = "C:\Mydata"
Get-ChildItem -Path $source | Copy-Item -Destination $dest -Recurse -Container
```

This just copies every file without filtering. I just need `image_xy.mat`
How can I accomplish this in powershell?

Comment: Filter it like this: Get-ChildItem -Path $source | where {$_.name -like "image_xy.mat"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "Filter"-parameter on the "Copy-Item" cmdlet.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $source | Copy-Item -Destination $dest -Recurse -Container -filter "image_xy.mat"
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted! Thanks @D.J.