# Powershell - Move Folders to a Different Location if it contains txt file

Tags: powershell

The following script find all folders containing txt files

```
PS D:\Testfolder> Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.txt | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectoryName -Unique
D:\Testfolder\2nd
D:\Testfolder\3rd
D:\Testfolder\4th
D:\Testfolder\5th
D:\Testfolder\first
```

Now I want to move these folders to

```
D:\Testfolder\_dn
```

So that it looks the following -

```
D:\Testfolder\_dn\2nd
D:\Testfolder\_dn\3rd
D:\Testfolder\_dn\4th
D:\Testfolder\_dn\5th
D:\Testfolder\_dn\first
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? Have any work to show? What part exactly are you stuck at? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. If you need help learning how to code or troubleshoot something then this is the place for you. If you need code from scratch then you should hire a developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432290/how-to-use-powershell-copy-item-and-keep-structure), you can do something like this -

```
$targetDir = 'D:\Testfolder\_dn'
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.txt | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectoryName -Unique | Move-Item -Destination $targetDir -Recurse -Container
```

Comment: worked for me : Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.txt | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectoryName -Unique | Move-Item -Destination 'D:\Testfolder\_dn'

Comment: If this answered your question then you should accept it as the answer.

Comment: I upvoted the answer but the last "-Recurse -Container" giving error in my ps prompt. So, I gave the code that worked for me in the comment. However, as you mentioned "Move-Item will accept input from the pipe", how can I use that value for example to move the folder to a relative path. I mean, if I use -Path, than what will be the variable after that?

Comment: Relative paths don't need a variable. They are literally relative to the item being moved

Comment: What I meant is suppose here the destination is 'D:\Testfolder\_dn'. But I want to move it to D:\Testfolder\2nd\..\_dn. So now I need the variable which has the value D:\Testfolder\2nd. So, now the last part will look like "Move-Item -Destination $_var"\..\_dn. What will be $_var.

Comment: That is not a relative path then it is a literal path